Trouble connecting Flutter app to realtime subscription on Supabase
I am working on a project that utilizes flutter and supabase for my backend. I am wanting to create a subscription to listen to realtime events. I've read all the supasebase docs and thought I followed all the instructions, but after creating my subscription it returns false on subscribe().canPush, which indicates that it is not connected to the socket.
I'm not receiving any errors in the console, and when I test realtime events here, I see the events occurring. Not sure, if it is a network security problem or what, but I'd appreciate some help. I am using my personal phone instead of an emulator to work on this project too.
I tried creating a subscription method to listen to realtime events, and was expecting to see newly created Receipt objects from my database through the subscription method.
Supabase Initialization:
await Supabase.initialize(
   url: '${dotenv.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL']}', 
   anonKey: '${dotenv.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY']}',
   realtimeClientOptions: const RealtimeClientOptions(
   eventsPerSecond: 2,
  ), 
);

Subscribe method:
final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
final subscription = supabase
    .channel('Receipt')
    .onPostgresChanges(
        event: PostgresChangeEvent.all,
        schema: 'public',
        callback: (payload) {
          print('Change received: ${payload.toString()}');
        })
    .subscribe();


Thank you for the suggestion Frank, fixed it
